# JavaScript - Changing div's onclick with a variable?

Tags: javascript

I've got a quick question:
I've got a function that stores id's in an array called "view1". When a certain requirement is met, I want these id's onclick to change. I want them to load a function called clickMem(id) when they are clicked, and also send in their id in the function. 
So I've tried this with the first id in the array and it didn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById(view1[0]).onclick='clickMem('+view1[0]+');';
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `onclick` expects a function, not a string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick

Comment: Setting the onclick event will do nothing but bind a function to the event.  The event needs to be triggered for something to happen.  From reading your question, it sounds like you want the function to run when the condition is met, not just bind the function and do nothing.  Am I right?

Comment: Oh, no, I just want to bind the function to the id.
I don't want it to run until the div with the id is clicked.
And I'm afraid the answers below doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 1):

Use [**setAttribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) :

```
  var new_onclick = 'clickMem('+view1[0]+')';
  document.getElementById(view1[0]).setAttribute('onclick',new_onclick);
```

But Note:

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = clickMem(view1[0]);
```

Sets the onclick property of the element to the result of `clickMem(view1[0])` as it would call
 that function and assign the value returned by that function to the `onclick` property, which is something you don't want.

So pass a `function(){clickMem(view1[0]);}`

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+id).onclick = function(){clickMem(view1[0]);}
```

which can also work .

Comment: why not document.getElementById(view1[0]).onclick=clickMem(view1[0]);?

Comment: @vivek_nk: That would execute `clickMem` immediately, not when the click event is triggered.

Comment: @Aditya: The result your `.onclick` solution is different from your `setAttribute` solution.

Comment: Yes i meant BUT not OR, updated answer and thanks a ton for pointing out there

Comment: I don't think "BUT" makes it clear enough what the difference is. Instead of writing a comment, I'd suggest to properly write two or three sentences about the differences, and really make clear that those are two different solutions. Why are suggestion two different solutions anyway?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that this did not work for me.

Also, wouldn't I need an extra ' character here? document.getElementById(view1[0]).setAttribute('onclick','clickMem('+view1[0]+');

Like this:

document.getElementById(view1[0]).setAttribute('onclick','clickMem('+view1[0]+') **'** ;

Comment: This works like a charm!
Thank you so much! I'm so happy that you help beginners like me with problems like these, I wish you all the best :)

Comment: Cool, Please accept this solution as the answer to your question thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById(view1[0]).onclick=function() {clickMem(view1[0]);}
```

Comment: You are assuming that `clickMem` returns a function, which it might not do.